# Reusing Case Statement for many Columns in same SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, user-defined-functions

I have a big table from a survey where all the answers are similar but I need to make them consistent. I need to reuse the same case statement for all the columns, however that would lead to a very ugly and long query. Is there a way to make a case into a stored procedure, UDF or something where I can just change the called column?

Examples:

```
-- Example Case statement I need for all Columns
    CASE 
            WHEN Happy IN ('Yes','True','Y','1') THEN 'Yes'
            WHEN Happy IN ('No','False','N','0') THEN 'No'
            WHEN Happy LIKE 'Don_t Know' or Happy IN ('Unknown','U','999','-1') THEN 'Unknown'
            WHEN Happy IN ('Missing','Blank','-4') THEN 'Missing'
    END AS HappyClean

-- Example table
SELECT Happy
      ,Sad
      ,DownBad
      ,FeelinGood
From Emotions
```

The actual number of Columns is over 50 and the Case is actually 2 lines longer so you can see how long the code would be if I had to copy paste that code for every column. I am using SQL Server btw.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: You could certainly encapsulate that in a function and pass the column as an argument.

Comment: That is a `CASE` **expression**, not statement. As for the question, though you *could* create a function (likely a scalar function that would be inlinable in 2019+) such methods don't scale well in SQL. Compartmentalising logic in T-SQL often hinders efficiency, not improves it. Often repeating the logic is actually more performant.

Comment: Perhaps, really you should have a column called `Feeling` and then another column for the true/false/etc. Then you only need 1 `CASE` expression, not 50. Such requirements do normally indicate a design flaw when you need to repeat an expression that many times.

Comment: You can pay the price ONCE to fix your data in some fashion by making in consistent and then use the "fixed" data in all your queries. Or you can pay the price with every single query. You choose.

Answer (score 2):

You can just create a mapping table, insert all the replacement pairs once, then join:

```
CREATE TABLE #Mapping
(
  Candidate varchar(255),
  Replacement varchar(255)
);

INSERT #Mapping(Candidate, Replacement)
VALUES('Yes','Yes'),('True','Yes'),('Y','Yes'),('1','Yes'),
  ('No','No'),('False','No'),('N','No'),('0','No'),
  ('Don_t Know','Unknown'),('Unknown','Unknown'),
  ('U','Unknown'),('999','Unknown'),('-1','Unknown'),
  ('Missing','Missing'),('Blank','Missing'),('-4','Missing');

UPDATE e SET Happy = m.Replacement
  FROM dbo.Emotions AS e
  INNER JOIN #Mapping AS m
  ON e.Happy LIKE m.Candidate;
```

Comment: Beat me to the punch (although I added `primary key` to Candidate) 

Comment: Curious, what does the `LIKE` on the `JOIN` do that `=` doesn't? I've never seen it done like this before.

Comment: @HardCode `LIKE` handles the case of `Don_t Know` from the question (`WHEN Happy LIKE 'Don_t Know'`) - the `_` is a wildcard, I presume they can have straight apostrophe `'` or smart apostrophe `’`.

Comment: Why not use left join then unknown values can be either left as `null` or `coalesce`d to unknown. Otherwise you will lose the line if `e.Happy LIKE m.Candidate`doesn't find a match.

Comment: @Kendle I'd rather not guess what the OP wants to do with edge case values they didn't include in their question. WIth an inner join any values not mentioned above will be left alone.

Comment: Thanks, @AaronBertrand. I forget that `_` is a wildcard. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a virtual `VALUES` table

```sql
SELECT
  HappyClean = m.Replacement
FROM dbo.Emotions AS e
INNER JOIN (VALUES
  ('Yes','Yes'),('True','Yes'),('Y','Yes'),('1','Yes'),
  ('No','No'),('False','No'),('N','No'),('0','No'),
  ('Don_t Know','Unknown'),('Unknown','Unknown'),
  ('U','Unknown'),('999','Unknown'),('-1','Unknown'),
  ('Missing','Missing'),('Blank','Missing'),('-4','Missing')
) AS m(Candidate, Replacement) ON e.Happy LIKE m.Candidate;
```

Answer (score 0):

I might create a mapping table and link to it in the query using left joins for those answers that still don't match with anything.

```
CREATE TABLE MAPPING (a nvarchar(100), b nvarchar(100))

INSERT INTO MAPPING
VALUES  ('Yes','Yes'),('True','Yes'),('Y','Yes'),('1','Yes'),
        ('No','No'),('False','No'),('N','No'),('0','No'),
        ('Don_t Know','Unknown'),('Unknown','Unknown'),
        ('U','Unknown'),('999','Unknown'),('-1','Unknown'),
        ('Missing','Missing'),('Blank','Missing'),('-4','Missing');

SELECT Happy
      ,m1.b as HappyResult
      ,Sad
      ,m2.b as SadResult
      ,DownBad
      ,m3.b as DownbadResult
      ,FeelinGood
      ,m4.b as FeelinGoodResult
From Emotions e
left join MAPPING m1 on m1.a = e.Happy
left join MAPPING m2 on m2.a = e.Sad
left join MAPPING m3 on m3.a = e.DownBad
left join MAPPING m4 on m4.a = e.FeelinGood
```